# What can I say in reply of "Get well soon"?

Tags: word-choice

I am in a bit confused, what can I say in reply of **Get well Soon.**

I generally say, **Thank you** .What are the other options ?

Comment: I'll do my best?

Comment: Might be better on [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) (but check their ["on-topic" help page](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: A curmudgeon might say, "I have other plans."

Comment: I reckon your answer - "*Thank you!*" - strikes the right balance between acknowledging the concern of the third party and communicating your gratitude for it.  Unless the relationship you have with the person is particularly close, any other response risks leaving one or other of you unclear and uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't feel like saying **thank you**, you can also say **"Will do"**.

While "will do" is more informal than "thank you", it is an acceptable idiom to use as a response.

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will%20do):

> 2 —used as an informal way of saying that one will be able to do something one is asked to do to
>   //"Can you finish it by tomorrow?" "Sure, boss, will do!"

Comment: Thanks, I just edited it to add a source and example.